# read data from a com port and write it to a text box in java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am trying to read data from a com port (barcode scanner) and write it to a text box. I'm relatively new to java, so I believe I'm missing something basic, but documentation on serial communications is limited. I am trying to get the input from the barcode reader to write to a text box named "txtONE" built in my fxml documentation. Here is my code:

```
    package javafxapplication7;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import gnu.io.CommPort;
    import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
    import gnu.io.SerialPort;
    import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
    import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    /**
     *

     */
    public class JavaFXApplication7 extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }

        public JavaFXApplication7()
        {
            super();
        }

        void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
        {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier =         CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
            if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
            }
    else
    {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

            serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this program.");
        }
    }     
}

/**
 * Handles the input coming from the serial port. A new line character
 * is treated as the end of a block in this example. 
 */
public static class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener 
{
    private InputStream in;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
        int data;

        try
        {
            int len = 0;
            while ( ( data = in.read()) > -1 )
            {
                if ( data == '\n' ) {
                    break;
                }
                buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
            }
            System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));
            txtOne.text = new String(buffer,0,len);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }             
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the output you expect, and what output do you get?

Comment: I am trying to get the data to write to a text box in my jframe names "txtOne", all I can manage is to get it to write to system out. It isn't recognizing txtONE.

Answer (score 0):

simple way for read com port in java, uses of JNI(java native interface) 
other way for reading barcode use of stored data, when data read and save(data base/file) read that with java. but i use serial port in java with JNI and you read of stored data have to be second way.